# Is there way to get the timestamp of the last enqueued message in Amazon SQS without actually reading the messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to know the last enqueued timestamp of a SQS queue without reading any messages from the queue ( as this is just for monitoring purposes.)

I explored [getQueueAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html)
but couldn't find any attribute that will tell us the timestamp of the last enqueued message.
Please let me know if there's any other way